# Chromecast API: how to cause heartbeat timeout to test connection recover

Tags: chromecast

I've implemented connection recovery and want to reliably re-create a heartbeat timeout (ping/pong response timeout) during my test cycles.   It appears that heartbeat is local between sender and receiver device? --- i am able to create sufficient network load to cause all of my other apps to time out.

I frequently get an intermittent "DisconnectWithError" event, but of course not frequent enough when I'm in my test cycle.

Perhaps I could take a walk outside the wifi range or programmatically disconnect and then invoke my error path (is there such a way? deviceManager.disconnect is not the way), but I was hoping for a more "engineering friendly external control" to cause the timeout.  Any thoughts or experiences?

log during hb timeout:

13:17:01  myapp[2588] : -[GCKHeartbeatChannel heartbeatTimerDidFire]  Ping out

13:17:01  myapp[2588] : -[GCKHeartbeatChannel inactivityTimerDidFire]  Max ping messages sent with no reponse - firing failure message!

13:17:01  myapp[2588] : -[GCKDeviceManager heartbeatChannelDidTimeout:]  Receiver not responding to heartbeat, disconnecting.

13:17:01  myapp[2588] : -[GCKCastSocket disconnect]  disconnect

13:17:01  myapp[2588] : -[GCKCastSocket disconnect]  waiting for write buffer to drain

13:17:01  myapp[2588] : -[GCKCastSocket doTeardownWithError:]  doTeardownWithError

13:17:01  myapp[2588] : -[GCKCastSocket doTeardownWithError:]  notifying delegate that socket is disconnected

13:17:01  myapp[2588] : -[GCKHeartbeatChannel didDisconnect]  disconnected - stopping heartbeat timer if necessary

Comment: If I recall correctly, if heartbeat is not reached the other side for 10 seconds, it assumes there is a network issue. On Android, what I usually do is turn off/on my wifi. Walking out of wifi range is also another option as you had mentioned; there is no programmatic way to adjust that number.

Answer (score 0):

another way i've been been able to programmatically cause a disconnect is by having another device or emulator attempt to get the Chromecast connection, which causes the app under test to get the disconnect event.